# Configurable Swatches Image Problems

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

I have the weirdest problem.  I think it has to do with an ERP we installed on Magento 1.9.3 but I'm not sure.  I have configurable products that have different sizes.  I use the configurable swatch to create a nice label for the sizes since I don't want to use drop down fields.  For the most part, the products came out correct.  However, when I add new products (after installing extension) I get a copy of the product image rather then labels.  Can someone help me troubleshoot the problem?

CORRECT 
http://c6341.sgvps.net/~msrhp/index.php/default/riding-gear/nxt-39/jackets/nxt-jersey-red-navy.html

INCORRECT
http://c6341.sgvps.net/~msrhp/index.php/default/riding-gear/legend-71/test/legend-71-jersey-black-yellow.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was no text with the images.  Once I added text, problem was solved.

[image]